# Get jobExecutionContext in xml config spring batch from before step

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am defining my **MultiResourceItemReader** on this way:

```
<bean id="multiDataItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="resources" value="#{jobExecutionContext['filesResource']}"/>
        <property name="delegate" ref="dataItemReader"/>
</bean>
```

How you can see I want read from the jobExecutionContext the "filesResource" value.

Note: I changed some names to keep the "code privacy". This is executing, Is somebody wants more info please tell me.

I am saving this value in my first step and I am using the reader in the second step, Should I have access to it?

I am saving it in the final lines from my step1 tasklet:

```
ExecutionContext jobContext = context.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext(); 
    jobContext.put("filesResource", resourceString); 


<batch:job id="myJob">

    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="moveFilesFromTasklet" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk commit-interval="500" 
                reader="multiDataItemReader" 
                processor="dataItemProcessor" 
                writer="dataItemWriter" />
        </tasklet>
    </batch:step>

</batch:job>
```

I am not really sure what I am forgetting to get the value. The error that I am getting is:

```
20190714 19:49:08.120 WARN   org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader [[ # ]] - No resources to read. Set strict=true if this should be an error condition.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your config. The value of `resourceString` should be an array of `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` as this is the parameter type of the `resources` attribute of `MultiResourceItemReader`.

You can pass an array or a list of `String` with the absolute path to each resource and it should work. Here is a quick example:

```
class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        List<String> resources = Arrays.asList(
                "/full/path/to/resource1",
                "/full/path/to/resource2");
        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()
                .put("filesResource", resources);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```